# How to remove message from queue by condition?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I get a messages from IBM MQ. How to delete message from queue by condition?

I tried to set gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR; but it didn't help me.

```
MQQueue queue = queueManager.accessQueue(e.getIbmQueue().trim(), CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE, null, null, null);

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                        gmo.options = MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE | MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_PROPERTIES_AS_Q_DEF | MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
gmo.matchOptions = MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
gmo.waitInterval = 50000;
byte[] body = null;
while (true) {
    try {
        queue.get(msg, gmo);
        body = new byte[msg.getMessageLength()];
        String businessIdFromIbm = msg.getStringProperty("usr.uuid");
        if (businessIdFromIbm.equals("123")) {
            //delete message
        }
        msg.clearMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The queue.get call in your sample above is a destructive get - the message will be logically removed from the queue during that call.

You're using a syncpoint, and so you will need to call queuemanager.commit() to complete the unit of work (or the syncpoint will be committed automatically if you call queuemanager.disconnect() ).

MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR is only valid if you have opened the queue for browse (CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE), and issued at least one browse against the queue so that your application has a valid message under its browse cursor.

If you want to browse the message, and then remove it with a second queue.get to remove the message under the browse cursor, your first queue.get will need to specify either MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST or MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT on the gmo.options; and then the second queue.get will need to provide MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR as the match options *without* either browse option set, in order to destructively remove the browsed message.

```
MQQueue queue = queueManager.accessQueue(e.getIbmQueue().trim(), CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE, null, null, null);

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE | CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_AS_Q_DEF | CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
gmo.matchOptions = MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
gmo.waitInterval = 50000;
byte[] body = null;
while (true) {
    try {
        queue.get(msg, gmo);
        body = new byte[msg.getMessageLength()];
        String businessIdFromIbm = msg.getStringProperty("usr.uuid");
        if (businessIdFromIbm.equals("123")) {
            //delete message
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo2 = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo2.options =  CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR | CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
            queue.get(msg, gmo2);
            // Be prepared to handle the case where the message has been removed by another application (or expired) and so you receive MQRC 2033
            queueManager.commit();
        }
        msg.clearMessage();
}
```

An alternate approach (which would require fewer calls to the queue manager, if that is an issue), would be to use the JMS API to MQ, and use a selector on the usr.uuid, such that only messages which have this set to 123 are returned to the application. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm

Comment: I don't think that last paragraph is correct.  It is not the queue manager that does the filtering but rather the JMS provider (i.e. JMS client library),  Hence, the JMS client library will still be browsing through the messages in the queue looking for the matching message based on a particular property.

Comment: Since V7, it is the queue manager that does the filtering @Roger

Comment: But it is not available for Java applications.

Comment: @Roger, it can't be used from the classes for Java API as that API doesn't offer a way to send the appropriate MQOD to the queue manager, but as Morag said from v7 onwards the MQ classes for JMS will pass the selector to the queue manager when opening the queue, so that selection is done at the QM side.

Answer (score 0):

You can read my full blog posting [here](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=5496). Here is the reader's digest version of it.

There is a misconception regarding MQ/JMS message based filtering. Some people think that the IBM MQ queue manager does something special for JMS applications that is not done for plain Java or C/C++/C#/COBOL applications. It is just NOT true.  Read the first paragraph of the [Message selectors in JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm) from the Knowledge Center for more information.  Note: For C/C++/C#/COBOL applications, they can use the SelectionString from MQOD structure to perform message selection.

I have created a Message Selector class for POJO MQ applications.

Here is a snippet of the MQTest12MS that shows you how to use the MessageSelector class.

```
ms = new MessageSelector(qMgr);
ms.openQueue(inputQName);
ms.setFilter("SomeNum", MessageSelector.Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, 123);

while (true)
{
   receiveMsg = ms.getMessage(startAtBeginning);

   // got the message, now go and do something with it.

   // set flag to continue rather than restart at the beginning.
   startAtBeginning = false;
}
ms.closeQueue();
```

Here is the MessageSelector class.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Class Name
 *  MessageSelector
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class will retrieve messages from a queue based on a filter.
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @license Apache 2 License
 */
public class MessageSelector
{
   public enum Conditions
   {
      EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_EQUAL;
   }

   private MQQueueManager  qMgr = null;
   private MQQueue         inQ = null;
   private String          filterName = null;
   private Conditions      filterCondition;
   private Object          filterValue = null;

   /**
    * The constructor
    * @param qMgr - must have a valid/active connection to the queue manager
    */
   public MessageSelector(MQQueueManager qMgr)
   {
      super();
      this.qMgr = qMgr;
   }

   /**
    * Open the queue for both browsing and destructive gets.
    * @param qName
    * @throws MQException
    */
   public void openQueue(String qName) throws MQException
   {
      inQ = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED);
   }

   /**
    * Close the queue.
    * @throws MQException
    */
   public void closeQueue() throws MQException
   {
      if (inQ != null)
         inQ.close();
   }

   /**
    * Set the filter name, condition and value.
    * @param name
    * @param condition
    * @param value
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   public void setFilter(String name, Conditions condition, Object value) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      if (name == null)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter name cannot be null.");
      else if ("".equals(name))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter name cannot be blank.");
      else if (value == null)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter value cannot be null.");

      if ( (value instanceof String) || (value instanceof Boolean) ||
           (value instanceof Byte)   || (value instanceof Byte[])  )
       {
          if ( (Conditions.EQUAL != condition) && (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL != condition) )
          {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter condition can only be EQUAL or NOT_EQUAL.");
          }
       }
       else if ( (value instanceof Integer) || (value instanceof Long) ||
                 (value instanceof Double)  || (value instanceof Float) )
       {
          if ( (Conditions.EQUAL != condition) && (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL != condition) &&
               (Conditions.LESS_THAN != condition) && (Conditions.LESS_THAN_EQUAL != condition) &&
               (Conditions.GREATER_THAN != condition) && (Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL != condition) )
          {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter condition must be one of the following: EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_EQUAL.");
          }
       }
       else
       {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Object type for Filter value.");
       }

      /**
       * Pass the checks, save the values
       */
      this.filterName = name;
      this.filterCondition = condition;
      this.filterValue = value;
   }

   /**
    * Retrieve the next matching message from the queue.
    * @param reset - Start over from the beginning of the queue.
    * @return
    * @throws MQException
    * @throws IOException
    */
   public MQMessage getMessage(boolean reset) throws MQException, IOException
   {
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
      if (reset)
         gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      else
         gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQMessage getMsg = null;

      while (true)
      {
         getMsg = new MQMessage();

         inQ.get(getMsg, gmo);

         if (performConditionalTest(getMsg))
         {
            deleteMessage();
            break;
         }

         gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      }

      return getMsg;
   }

   /**
    * Handle the conditional testing of the value.
    * @param getMsg
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean performConditionalTest(MQMessage getMsg)
   {
      boolean flag = false;

      try
      {
         if (filterValue instanceof String)
         {
            String value = getMsg.getStringProperty(filterName);
            if (value != null)
            {
               if ( (Conditions.EQUAL == filterCondition) && (((String)filterValue).equals(value)) )
                  flag = true;
               else if ( (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (!(((String)filterValue).equals(value))) )
                  flag = true;
            }
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Integer)
         {
            int value = getMsg.getIntProperty(filterName);

            if ( (Conditions.EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value == (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value != (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN == filterCondition) && (value < (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value <= (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN == filterCondition) && (value > (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value >= (Integer)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Long)
         {
            long value = getMsg.getLongProperty(filterName);

            if ( (Conditions.EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value == (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value != (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN == filterCondition) && (value < (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value <= (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN == filterCondition) && (value > (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value >= (Long)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Double)
         {
            double value = getMsg.getDoubleProperty(filterName);

            if ( (Conditions.EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value == (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value != (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN == filterCondition) && (value < (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value <= (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN == filterCondition) && (value > (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value >= (Double)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Float)
         {
            float value = getMsg.getFloatProperty(filterName);

            if ( (Conditions.EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value == (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.NOT_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value != (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN == filterCondition) && (value < (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.LESS_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value <= (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN == filterCondition) && (value > (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
            else if ( (Conditions.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL == filterCondition) && (value >= (Float)filterValue) )
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Boolean)
         {
            Boolean value = getMsg.getBooleanProperty(filterName);
            if ( (value != null) && ((Boolean)filterValue == value) )
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Byte)
         {
            byte value = getMsg.getByteProperty(filterName);
            if ((Byte)filterValue == value)
               flag = true;
         }
         else if (filterValue instanceof Byte[])
         {
            byte[] value = getMsg.getBytesProperty(filterName);
            if ( (value != null) && (java.util.Arrays.equals((byte[])filterValue, value)) )
               flag = true;
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {}

      return flag;
   }

   /**
    * Delete the message that the cursor is pointing to.
    */
   private void deleteMessage()
   {
      MQMessage deleteMsg = new MQMessage();
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
      gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG;

      /**
       * don't need it - because we already have the message
       * just delete it.
       */
      try
      {
         inQ.get(deleteMsg, gmo, 1);  // only get 1 byte - who cares right!!
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {}
   }
}
```

Update 2019/06/25: I updated the setFilter method of the MessageSelector class.

Comment: This seems to be an illustration of how to avoid letting the queue manager do the filtering for you? The queue manager can filter on message properties using the MQOD field called SelectionString

Comment: If the IBM MQ team implemented all of the available MQ API calls for Java and C# applications then this would not be necessary but the SelectionString from MQOD structure is not avilable to Java and C# applications.

Comment: The Java classes are stabilized so there won't be any changes made to them. I don't know why the c# classes have not been updated - worth an RFE?